# Super slow execution plan for DISTINCT, not sure why

Tags: sql, sql-server

Version: SQL Server 2014 Enterprise.

I have a complex query that returns `3 integer columns - 428 rows in total`. Some of these rows are duplicates (all 3 columns match). Results are returned in *millisecs*.

If I use the SQL `distinct` keyword, it returns the correct result of 2 rows at the cost of *7 seconds*.

If I use `CTE` to isolate the execution plan of the original query from the `DISTINCT` in the `CTE` - still *7 seconds*. Why?

If I put my `428 rows of results` to an empty table of 3 columns and run `select distinct c1, c2, c3 from newtable` I get the correct 2 rows back in `milliseconds`.

So my questions are:

1. Why does the `DISTINCT` alter execution plan at all, why is it not just processing the rows after all other aspects of the query is done?

2- How can I distinctify the result in SQL in `millisecs` without `DISTINCT`?

Addendum: original query without distinct:

```
SELECT 
    coopterm0_.id AS x0_0_, coopterm0_.jobPostingTerm AS x1_0_, 
    coopterm0_.currentJobSearchTerm AS x2_0_ 
FROM 
    coop_term coopterm0_, 
    np_posting nposting1_ 
WHERE 
    (coopterm0_.jobPostingTerm = nposting1_.term) 
    AND (nposting1_.status IN (4, 6)) 
    AND (nposting1_.term IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (nposting1_.term IN (391, 392, 393, 410, 411, 412, 413, 415, 416 )) 
    AND ((( nposting1_.dateLastSaved >= '2019-01-20 16:00:00') 
          OR (EXISTS (SELECT napplication2_.id 
                      FROM np_application napplication2_ 
                      WHERE (napplication2_.job = nposting1_.id) 
                        AND (napplication2_.dateApplied >= '2019-01-20 16:00:00')))  
          OR (EXISTS (SELECT npostingview3_.id 
                      FROM np_posting_view npostingview3_ 
                      WHERE (npostingview3_.posting = nposting1_.id) 
                        AND (npostingview3_.dateViewed >= '2019-01-20 16:00:00')))))
```

Running both of these cut down execution time to 2 seconds, still 1000x slower then without distinct: UPDATE STATISTICS np_posting_view WITH FULLSCAN; update statistics np_application with fullscan;

Execution plans for Distinct (slow): brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkQrhRXm4 Non-distinct (quick): brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJYdnA7mE

Comment: Can we see the query or at least a representative example of it?

Comment: You can try using `group by` - that can sometimes perform better than distinct.

Comment: Post both queries and their execution plans.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to upload the different execution plans, but I compared them in SSMS and long story short, including the DISTINCT keyword totally changes the execution plan which now incorrectly estimate row sizes, picking different indexes etc. Differences are significant.

Comment: That complex query would be useful. As a senior DBA with 25 years experience I’m sure you realize we need the execution plans and a MCVE which includes the DDLs for the tables, views, functions, etc. Since you are senior I’m sure you have heard of Dr Dewitt as well so I’d encourage watching his video on why optimization is so hard to get right. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RQfJkNqmHB4#

Comment: Running both of these cut down execution time to 2 seconds, still 1000x slower then without distinct: UPDATE STATISTICS np_posting_view WITH FULLSCAN;
update statistics np_application with fullscan;

Comment: This is how you show the execution plans. Most everyone is aware of how to save them...  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: I understand the need to post everything (there is NDA involved here that prevents me from posting more), but my question is more fundamental: introducing the DISTINCT keyword changes execution plan, and not simply distinctifies the results of the underlying plan.

Comment: I can and did save them; well aware of how to do it. What I don't know is how to post it to stack overflow.

Comment: You post the link from that site, where you upload them. It is not surprising that updating the statistics would make the query faster since the optimizer would then have accurate statistics for the resources it requests like memory, CPU, etc.  and distinct would make almost every query slower since it is another operation that has to be performed

Comment: Distinct: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkQrhRXm4 Nondistinct: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJYdnA7mE

Comment: Rather than adding new information in hard to read comments, can you please edit the info directly into your question. Thanks

Comment: Added new information from comment section to the question text.

Comment: I vote to shift this question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server. This is nice question. Can you revise your question once more ?.I think your question asked and those two plan are different

Answer (score 0):

First of all use variable in place of constant to Test your query.It give more real execution plan.And provide Actual Execution Plan.

IMO,your query is not written properly so Optimizer is not able to create constant or better plan to execute your query.

It is not clear whats your query in case of CTE or in case Distinct because it depends.

you must have notice that predicate of  `np_posting nposting1_` are evaluating multiple times in one of your queries.

One of the reason is because of `Bracket`.There is wrong group of Bracket in your query.

Bracket influence the `Optimizer` way of evaluating the `Predicate`.

If resultset of `np_posting nposting1` is small then put them in `CTE` else put them in `Temp` table.

> How can I distinctify the result in SQL in millisecs without DISTINCT?

You can avoid using Distinct operator,becasue cost of distinct operator is always verify high .
`Distinct operator` :First get all rows then eliminate duplicate rows.
`Group BY` : It will start removing duplicate rows from the start.

Try this ,

```
DECLARE @Date datetime='2019-01-20 16:00:00'

With CTE AS(
SELECT term ,id
FROM np_posting nposting1_ 
WHERE ( nposting1_.status IN(4, 6)
 AND 
nposting1_.term IS NOT NULL AND  nposting1_.term IN ( 391, 392, 393, 410, 411, 412, 413, 415, 416 )  
AND  nposting1_.dateLastSaved >= @Date )
OR 
( EXISTS ( SELECT napplication2_.id FROM np_application napplication2_ WHERE  napplication2_.job = nposting1_.id  
AND  napplication2_.dateApplied >= @Date  ) )
OR 
( EXISTS ( SELECT npostingview3_.id FROM np_posting_view npostingview3_ 
WHERE  npostingview3_.posting = nposting1_.id  AND  npostingview3_.dateViewed >= @Date  ) ) 
)

SELECT  coopterm0_.id AS x0_0_, coopterm0_.jobPostingTerm AS x1_0_, coopterm0_.currentJobSearchTerm AS x2_0_ 
FROM coop_term coopterm0_
inner join  CTE nposting1_ 
on  coopterm0_.jobPostingTerm = nposting1_.term  
group by coopterm0_.id,coopterm0_.jobPostingTerm,coopterm0_.currentJobSearchTerm
```